# jQuery: controlling the speed of an element that moves randomly

Tags: jquery, animation

I have this code that works just fine. It moves an element inside a container randomly. The issue is that I can't controll the speed of the element; i've tried several solutions (like the normal duration of the animation method) but none of them worked. Any help would be apreciated. The code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  animateDiv();
});

function makeNewPosition() {
  var h = $('.main-translucid').height() - 50;
  var w = $('.main-translucid').width() - 50;

  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

  return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv() {
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  $('.fly').animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1],
    right: newq[0],
    bottom: newq[0]
  }, function() {
    animateDiv();
  });
};
```

The Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hjtkesaj/

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: I'm sorry a cant put the fiddle working, I'll post the rest of the code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hjtkesaj/ (feel free to add it to the question)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ddhfpsv7/ with an added duration parameter, 5 seconds in this example. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes this is it...but i dont get it, i've tried this...my guess was syntax...thank you :)

Comment: alright, I'll write up an answer for internet points ;)

Comment: more than welcome, be my guest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) accepts an optional `duration` parameter in milliseconds after the properties. An example to make the fly take 5 seconds per iteration:

```
function animateDiv() {
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  $('.fly').animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1],
    right: newq[0],
    bottom: newq[0]
  }, 5000, function() {
    animateDiv();
  });
};
```

([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddhfpsv7/))

Randomizing this value for each iteration might be a good way to create a cheap illusion of fly-like chaotic movement.